# Access private member vector of multiple objects in other class

Tags: c++, c++11, encapsulation

I have two classes (A & B) with a similar structure, which both contain a vector of structs.

```
class A/B{
private: std::vector<DataStruct> vec_A/vec_B;
...
public:
...
}
```

To create/update an object of B, I have to combine the data from the vectors of multiple objects of class A (combining similar entries in the vector into one entry in the vector of object B and do data transformations in B).

**How do I do this?**

My thoughts were:

- Making class B a friend of A. But I've heard, that making classes friends in C++ is only the last resort and should be avoided.
- Writing a `getVector()` function in class A, which returns a reference to the Vector `vec_A`, so that class B can operate on the data. For me this seems to simply bypass the data encapsulation. What would be the advantage to setting the vector to public?
- Writing a `getVector()` function in class A, which returns a copy of `vec_A`. But as `vec_A` is not that small, this seems to be inefficient (ok, only a few kB. Should work but in general...)
- Write a function for class A, which does the calculation and creates an object of class B. Then concatenate multiple objects of B into one final object of B. However, this seems to be a lot of overhead to me.

Comment: have you considered giving B a const reference of `vec_A` ?

Comment: @Xatyrian no, but this seems to be a good Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Writing a `getVector()` function in class A, which returns a reference
>   to the `Vector vec_A`, so that class B can operate on the data. For me
>   this seems to simply bypass the data encapsulation. What would be the
>   advantage to setting the vector to public?

If B just needs to observe the content of `vec_A`, consider returning a **`const`** reference (`const &`):

```
class A {
 ...
  public:

    // Give read-only access to vec_A
    const std::vector<DataStruct> & getVector() const {
        return vec_A;
    }
};
```

I prefer this solution to just making the vector data member public: with accessors (getter/setter) you have better control. For example you can implement a read-only access (like shown above). Or, if you want to provide a setter, you can also implement some checking on the input argument, etc.